# Why are free electrons free?

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

This is what I understand so far: in a conductor, the ions have a weak pull on the valence electrons. So when an electric field is applied, the free electrons are able to easily move about. Makes sense.

In a neutral conductor with no electric field, the free electrons aren't bound to any ions. Why? I understand that the ions have a weak pull on the electrons, but what makes electrons leave the ion and stay free?

Comment: This might help http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_bonding

Comment: This is a subject where it *really* helps to have the math. You have asked dozens of question on the behavior of electrons in conductors. That level of curiosity deserves a better understanding than you are going to get from fuzzy word pictures. You'd be doing yourself a huge favor if you stopped asking for still more word pictures and put that same energy into learning the math.

Comment: @dmckee I *am* currently working on learning the math. I'm simply taking the courses my school requires me too, and at this point we just haven't learn't enough math for me to understand this mathematically. Unless single variable calculus and linear algebra is enough, I'm going to have to live with fuzzy word pictures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An atom in isolation offers a potential well, and electrons form bound states in the well. The energy of those bound states can be calculated exactly in the case of a single-electron (hydrogen-like) atoms or by variational computational methods for more complicated cases.

Now when you put several atoms together in a tight and regular array, they offer a combined well resulting from the sum of all their potentials.

That combined well might look (in cartoon form) something like this:
[image]

Here the red lines represent electron energy level that are still contained by the locally stronger effect of their "own" nucleus, but the blue line represents those slightly higher energy levels that see the combined potential as a single large energy well (with some high-frequency detailed structure).

In a conductor, non-conduction electrons fill *all* the red (local) energy levels and the remaining electrons must (because of Pauli exclusion) then occupy the blue (non-localized) conduction levels.

Comment: This is the most concise and clear explanation that I have found on the matter! However, how does hole conductivity in semiconductors fit into this picture? How does a valence electron ("red" electron) jump into a nearby potential well?

Comment: @akhmed Two thing contrinute to the behavior of a semi-conductor. First the locally bound states (the one I marked in red)  are almost completely filled, but there no electrons forced into the conduction band by default. Second there is a small, but non-trivial energy difference (called the "band gap") between the highest red state and the lowest blue one. The result is that the material is not a conductor by default but you don't have to supply much energy to get some electrons into the conduction band.

Comment: thanks! I was not very clear - I was referring to p-type semiconductors. The explanations typically say that in p-type semiconductors the valence electrons (at least the ones responsible for conductivity) never actually go to conduction band and instead seem to jump from a "red" energy level directly to a "nearby" "red" energy level. From your picture, I understand that the potential barrier that separates two nearby wells must be low enough in comparison to the highest "red" energy level for that to happen. Would that be a reasonable description?

Comment: Ah. I'm rapidly getting out of my depth here. As I recall the system exhibits effective degree's of freedom (called "holes") which behave like positively charged particles and exhibit a dynamics essentially the same as electrons in n-type semi-conductors. But I'm not sure of any of the details.

Comment: I think I found the answer! p-doping creates an additional low-energy conduction band very close to valence band in semiconductors (while n-doping creates an additional high-energy valence band close to conduction band). https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Map%3A_General_Chemistry_(Petrucci_et_al.)/11%3A_Chemical_Bonding_II%3A_Additional_Aspects/11.7%3A_Bonding_in_Metals

Comment: By the way, here is the **exact** answer (fully confirming your answer as well!) http://www.chem1.com/acad/webtext/chembond/cb10.html

Answer (score 2):

In a single free atom, electrons have well defined energy levels and are somewhat bound to atom. Consider the following quantum mechanical model of atom to get an idea about an isolated atom.
[image]

When all this isolated atoms come together to form the crystal, the atoms do not have well defined energy levels.  There will be molecular orbitals. When the atoms get even closer, energy bands are formed which are continuous variation of energy levels. Continuous energy level mean electrons are somewhat free to move. Energy bands splits into valence and conduction band. These two bands are separated by certain energy gap. Depending on this energy gap, materials are distinguished as conductors, insulators, and semiconductors.

The energy required to attain energy level of conduction band is obtained by applying even small electric field in conductors. So, formation of continuous variation of energy levels makes electrons to be free.

Answer (score 1):

The intuition is that the valence electrons are so far away from their nucleus that when they combine to form metals, they feel the attraction of all the other nuclei as strongly as from theirs.

In a more rigorous description, the orbitals for the valence electrons fully overlap with their neighbouring atoms, so their "play field" extends all over the material.

Comment: But wouldn't only the nucleuses in relatively close proximity have as strong a force on the electron as its own nucleus? So shouldn't it only be able to move between nearby atoms?

Comment: @dfg For low lying shell yes, but more energetic shells have a larger physical extant and if they are big enough they extend into regions where other nuclei are stronger. For a regular atomic structure that results in them be captured in a well by *all* the metal nuclei rather than locally by one nucleus. There is a cartoon of the situation in my answer. But I repeat that to really understand this (rather than just collecting half understood facts) you're going to have to learn the math.

Comment: @dfg I don't know if this will help, but:  think of benzene.  Each carbon atom has a set of electrons that stay nearby in states associated with the atom.  But the highest occupied molecular orbital is delocalized:  electrons in that orbital are in a state associated with *the entire molecule*.  Same thing happens in metals.  Same thing happens in some polymers, and they behave in many respects (like conductivity) like metals.

Comment: Once it is able to move to the next atom, it can as well forget it comes from the previous one and jump to the following one. In a way, it can travel through atoms.